# using different number of parameters for sqldatasource insert and update

Tags: asp.net, sqldatasource

I have a sqldatasource with insert and update commands.  I list 10 user fields in the detailsview that uses the sqldatasource.  However, when i insert, I insert all 10 fields, but when I update, I only want to update 8 fields.  This is causing a problem because I believe all 10 fields displayed are being passed as parameters even though my insertparameters and updateparameters sections are declared with the appropriate number of parameters.  Is there a way I can easily insert all 10 parameters but only send 8 to the update stored procedure?

Answer (score 1):

Change the UpdateCommand and its parameters from the generated ones to what you want.